# Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E) when running Matplotlib on Pycharm

Tags: matplotlib, plot, error-handling, pycharm

I have started experiencing an annoying problem when running matplotlib.pyplot on Pycharm. I was writing a code which plots a domain in the [0,1] box and an heatmap. All of a sudden, while I was working, the plots stopped showing up, and, instead the following message

"Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)"

started showing up.

It is necessarily related to matplotlib, since every time I comment the "import matplotlib.pyplot" line (and all the lines which make use of pyplot), the error does not appear. Moreover, when I moved the same exact script to Google Colab, the code worked again and the plots appeared correctly.
If it can help, I am using the latest version of matplotlib (3.8.3) on Pycharm 2023.3.4